# Unable to select a dropdown by value, visible text or index using selenium select command

Tags: selenium, drop-down-menu

I am unable to select an option dynamically using select commands by value, visible text or index, the workaround was i can use actions to click select and select a particular option or sending keys ArrowDown which is not a best way to implement because i want to use the same select function globally to automate UI all over the website like a keyword function.

sample script below:

```
WebElement selectElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath(.//*[@id='XYZPopUpForm:j_idt90:country_label']));

Actions selectItem = new Actions(driver);
selectItem.moveToElement(selectElement).click().perform();  
selectItem.sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).perform();
selectItem.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER).perform();
```

HTML Code :

```
<tr>
<td>
<label for="XYZPopUpForm:j_idt90:country">Country</label>
</td>
<td>
<div id="XYZPopUpForm:j_idt90:country" class="ui-selectonemenu ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all">
<div class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible">
<div class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible">
<select id="XYZPopUpForm:j_idt90:country_input" tabindex="-1" name="XYZPopUpForm:j_idt90:country_input">
<option selected="selected" disabled="disabled">--select--</option>
<option value="AF">Afghanistan</option>
<option value="AX">Åland Islands</option>
<option value="AL">Albania</option>
<option value="DZ">Algeria</option>
<option value="AS">American Samoa</option>
<option value="AD">Andorra</option>
<option value="AO">Angola</option>
<option value="AI">Anguilla</option>
<option value="AQ">Antarctica</option>
<option value="AG">Antigua and Barbuda</option>
<option value="AR">Argentina</option>
<option value="AM">Armenia</option>
<option value="AW">Aruba</option>
<option value="AU">Australia</option>
<option value="AT">Austria</option>
<option value="AZ">Azerbaijan</option>
<option value="BS">Bahamas</option>
<option value="BH">Bahrain</option>
<option value="BD">Bangladesh</option>
<option value="BB">Barbados</option>
<option value="BY">Belarus</option>
<option value="BE">Belgium</option>
<option value="BZ">Belize</option>
<option value="BJ">Benin</option>
<option value="BM">Bermuda</option>
<option value="BT">Bhutan</option>
<option value="BO">Bolivia, Plurinational State of</option>
<option value="BQ">Bonaire, Sint Eustatius and Saba</option>
<option value="BA">Bosnia and Herzegovina</option>
<option value="BW">Botswana</option>
<option value="BV">Bouvet Island</option>
<option value="BR">Brazil</option>
<option value="IO">British Indian Ocean Territory</option>
<option value="BN">Brunei Darussalam</option>
<option value="BG">Bulgaria</option>
<option value="BF">Burkina Faso</option>
<option value="BI">Burundi</option>
<option value="KH">Cambodia</option>
<option value="CM">Cameroon</option>
<option value="CA">Canada</option>
<option value="CV">Cape Verde</option>
</select>
</div>
```

Updated Script:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
WebElement selectElement = driver.findElement(By.id("XYZPopUpForm:j_idt90:country_input"));
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("var select = arguments[0]; for(var i = 0; i < select.options.length; i++){ if(select.options[i].text == arguments[1]){ select.options[i].selected = true; } } ", selectElement, "Afghanistan");
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("XYZPopUpForm:j_idt90:country_input")));
```

Screenshot of HTML to be more clear :

[image: https]

Comment: Why is it not working using `Select`?? is there any exception??? Need to share dropdown HTML as well...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you are finding incorrect element `By.xpath` your drop-down id looks like `XYZPopUpForm:j_idt90:country_input` but you are finding `id` `XYZPopUpForm:j_idt90:country_label` in `By.xpath`, May be that is the problem. Try using `Select` with correct drop-down `id` as below :-

```
WebElement selectElement = driver.findElement(By.id("XYZPopUpForm:j_idt90:country_input"));

//Now use select
Select select = new Select(selectElement);
select.selectByVisibleText("Afghanistan");
```

or

```
sel.selectByIndex(1);
```

or

```
sel.selectByValue("AF");
```

**Edited** :- If above does not work due to visibility of element you should try using  `JavascriptExecutor` as below :-

```
WebElement selectElement = driver.findElement(By.id("XYZPopUpForm:j_idt90:country_input"));

((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("var select = arguments[0]; for(var i = 0; i < select.options.length; i++){ if(select.options[i].text == arguments[1]){ select.options[i].selected = true; } }", selectElement, "Afghanistan");
```

Hope it works...:)

Comment: @Saurabh....Good effort!! but it didnt work i get "Not able to select element --- element not visible: Element is not currently visible and may not be manipulated".

Comment: @Camreyjones If above does not work due to visibility of element you should try using JavascriptExecutor..see updated answer...:)

Comment: Another brilliant effort!! it looks like its working in the background as i dont get any errors in the log file, but the UI is not showing this change, when i click the dropdown twice then its selecting the value "Afghanistan". Do you recon a wait here please?

Comment: @Camreyjones yes you need to implement WebDriverWait here until element present...

Comment: thanks again i was away since yesterday, i just tried again with wait but it doesnt seem to update UI might me i am giving a wrong one, please bare with me as i am new to these complex things. I have mentioned my script above as 'Updated Script'. Thanks

Comment: @Camreyjones You are going wrong try as :- `WebDriverWait(driver, 10); WebElement selectElement = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("obligorPopUpForm:j_idt90:country_input")));((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("var select = arguments[0]; for(var i = 0; i < select.options.length; i++){ if(select.options[i].text == arguments[1]){ select.options[i].selected = true; } } ", selectElement, "Afghanistan"); ` need to wait before selecting..try this

Comment: Actually this line `wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("obligorPopUpForm‌​:j_idt90:country_input")));` will wait until element visible on the page with 10 second and if found it will return the WebElement also..so need to replace `driver.findElement` line with this...and omit from the last..:)

Comment: no luck Saurabh :( it says Not able to select element --- Timed out after 10 seconds waiting for visibility of element located by By.id: XYZPopUpForm:j_idt90:country_input (is it worth trying with CSS Selector please?)

Comment: @Camreyjones once try with change this line `ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated` to this line `ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated` and let me know...

Comment: Luckily no errors this time Saurabh!! but no change in UI :( i have attached screenshot of HTML to be more precise. thanks

Comment: Try To select  option using by this :- `((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("var select = arguments[0]; for(var i = 0; i < select.options.length; i++){ if(select.options[i].text.indexOf(arguments[1]) != -1){ select.options[i].selected = true; } } ", selectElement, "Afghanistan");` ..and let me know

Comment: @Camreyjones I have do some correction in JavaScript..try with above comment and let me know..:)

Comment: @Camreyjones If above does not work try with this :- `((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("var select = arguments[0]; for(var i = 0; i < select.options.length; i++){ if(select.options[i].value == arguments[1]){ select.options[i].selected = true; } } ", selectElement, "AF");`

Comment: Hi Saurabh thanks again, i see what you are trying to make it work with index and value?? they did work in the background too but no changes on UI. I have seen similar questions on this website and can you see if they are relating to my issue please. (http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/13923/selenium-web-driver-drop-down-list-testing-with-div-tag-in-java)

Comment: Sorry Saurabh, technically your solution works in the background but not visible on UI, i have taken out the tick for the solution so not to misguide you but if you are out of answers, i will leave the tick back. :)

Comment: @Camreyjones I'm sorry but didn't understand what do you mean not visible on UI?? Would you explain more??

Comment: the javascript work behind the scenes but the "option" is not selected on UI it gets selected only when i click the drop down twice.

Comment: The JavascriptExecutor solution worked pretty well for me (in Chrome, with the application running Angular). The other solutions only worked sometimes on some dropdowns,